# BSOD with DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION

Tags: windows-10, freeze, bsod, dpc

For the last week I'm suffering from a hand and BSOD in Windows 10 Pro. I didn't changed hardware and I cannot remember any update, but it is possible Windows updated my computer while shutting down (it does it regularly, so I didn't payed attention anymore).

The behavior is: the computer boots normally, everything appears to be running smoothly and after a few minutes (around 5 minutes), it almost hangs (mouse still moving), 5 seconds later it is completely hung (mouse doesn't move), and in 10 extra seconds I get to a BSOD with the only reference of DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION.

The behavior is the same if I boot in safe mode.

After reading available information, it looks like it could be a hardware problem or a driver problem. I tried to reinstall a few drivers (named in the forums), but it didn't work. I also ran the standard memory test and half of the extended memory test and no errors aroused.

By using NirSoft's BlueScreenView, I managed to track down the problem to the HAL (which is like saying nothing to me... it could be anything).

Any idea of what I can try? Any place where I can see which is the hardware piece it is causing trouble? Once I find it, I can try to update the driver or disconnect/replace the faulty part.

UPDATE:

I managed to get into safe mode with command line and run `sfc /scannow`. It ran for some time, up to 25%, without issues, then the system got the BSOD. As long as the system boots into Windows, I have very few minutes to do whatever I have to do. Longer operations will be stopped by the BSOD.

I also ran the extended memory test. No failures until I went to sleep. When I woke up, the computer was on, but no screen signal. I can try to ask the system to repeat the test multiple times in order to survive the night. I will update if I get better results.

Comment: If you can get into Safe Mode - Command Prompt, then you can try a sfc /scannow. Otherwise, run a full Memtest

Comment: You might check for a BIOS update. The important drivers are BIOS, Chipset, Display Driver, Network .

Comment: @Stese, I updated the question with the information requested. Nothing bad seen in the period those test could run.

Comment: @harrymc, I updated the Display Driver. Chipset and network would belong to the mainboard. BIOS could be dangerous, but I can give it a try. Anyways, nothing changed neither in those drivers nor the associated hardware before the BSODs started to appear.

Comment: OK, a BIOS update is not absolutely indicated for the moment. Have a look in the Event Viewer for useful messages.

Comment: I won't post this as an answer as its only a link. It would be good if you can write an answer stating which section fixed your issue (if at all). https://thewindowsplus.org/dpc_watchdog_violation/

Comment: @Stese, I think I already tried all of them, but this night I will do a thorough  traversal of that list, thanks.

Comment: @Stese, I have almost all results of that link. I turned off fast startup. I tried to check for a corrupted hard drive, but it was not fast enough and it got to the BSOD after 27%. I updated the chipset driver, the one used was not the one the page says it should be, beu is the one I always used and completed the procedure. I uninstalled the display driver in safe mode, and it has been automativally installed again at restart, as expected. I installed all the available Windows updates but the last one, that was released yesterday (BSOD before finishing).

Comment: if the machine is not stable enough to finish a full disk check, i'd suggest using a live-cd or similar to do the check... you are ruling out software issues then, as the drive is not used for boot.

Comment: The only step left to do is the system restore, but for this I want to do a backup, just in case. For this, I'm using a USB-booted Ubuntu. Once there, I mounted my system drive, but I'm gettintg I/O errors while reading files. Looking at the output of fdisk -l I can see the internals of my system drive. It is an OCZ Revodrive X2 composed of 4 drives in RAID0 and shown to Windows as a single drive. In Linux, I access them through the device mapper but can still see them independently.

Comment: I/O Errors? That indicates a faulty disk or controller.

Comment: 3 out of 4 of those disks appear to be in good shape, but one of them cannot be properly analyzed. `smartctl -i` manages to show data for all of them but one. So it looks like the issue if a hardware issue with my system drive.

Comment: But I'm surprised how Windows is able to boot and work flawlessly for around 5 minutes until the timeout expires and the BSOD appears.

Comment: The system is no exactly unstable. I gets to the BSOD after a fixed amount of time. There's some timeout expiring and causing that. So all operations to solve the problem must be done in that timeframe :-(

Comment: The only thing I still have to do is check that this is really the cause (validate the hardware failure). And try to recover some data from that drive. Anyways, no big deal. Important data is already in an external RAID5 with a backup on a secondary drive.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll come back when I have more solid conclussions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the comments.

Finally the problem came due to a faulty SSD. It was an OCZ Revodrive X2, an old SSD that connected directly to the PCIe bus to overcome the limits of the SATA connection. That card internally had 4 SSD drives in a RAID 0 configuration, ant it was offered as a single drive to the OS by the driver (although under Linux you could see the four sub-units). One of this sub-unit was starting to fail.

It is surprising that the system still booted from that SSD, and apparently everything worked fine and files were readable until the BSOD. Using Linux, it was more apparent that one of the sub-units was not properly accessible (fdisk info, lsblk info...).

Once the suspect was clear, I backed up the few things of interest that remained in that drive with no other copies and substituted that unit by a standard SSD thru SATA interface (PCIe SSD are no longer produced, and moving to an M.2 interface implied an extra adaptor card and the overall cost would nearly double for a probably not-so-noticeable speed increment). I installed a fresh copy of the OS and so far no new problems appeared, so now the veredict is reassured: it was a dying SSD. It serviced me well for around 8 years. Time to let it go to the SSD heaven.